# Exercise $1$ p.$428$ Hatcher (property of Hopf Invariant)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, spheres

I'd like to prove the following properties Hopf Invariant, which are Exercises at pag $428$ on Hatcher but I can't find any reference or proof.

I think I have to use directly the eaxct long sequence used to define the Hopf Invariant $H$, but I don't undertstand how the degree comes in play

[image]

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition of the Hopf invariant: given a map $f: S^{2n-1} \to S^n$, we form the mapping cone $C_f$, whose cohomology is given by $\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees $n$ and $2n$.  Taking $\alpha \in H^n(C_f)$ and $\beta \in H^{2n}(C_f)$ to be generators, the Hopf invariant is the integer $H(f)$ satisfying $\alpha^2 = H(f) \beta$.

Now, given $S^{2n-1} \xrightarrow{f} S^{2n-1} \xrightarrow{g} S^n$, consider the map of cofiber sequences
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^n @>>> C_{gf} @>>> S^{2n}\\
@VVV @VVV @VV{-\Sigma f}V \\
S^n @>>> C_g @>>> S^{2n}.
\end{CD}$$
Writing $\alpha, \beta$ (resp. $\alpha', \beta'$) for the generators in cohomology for the spheres in the top (resp. bottom) row, we have $\alpha'^2 = H(g) \beta'$.  Pulling this equation back to the top row, we see that $\alpha^2 = H(g) (\deg f \cdot \beta)$.  Since $H(gf)$ is defined so that $\alpha^2 = H(gf) \beta$, we deduce that $H(gf) = (\deg f) \cdot H(g)$.

For $S^{2n-1} \xrightarrow{f} S^n \xrightarrow{g} S^n$, we have
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^n @>>> C_f @>>> S^{2n}\\
@V{g}VV @VVV @VVV \\
S^n @>>> C_{gf} @>>> S^{2n}.
\end{CD}$$

Writing $\alpha, \beta$ (resp. $\alpha', \beta'$) for the generators in cohomology for the spheres in the bottom (resp. top) row, we have $\alpha^2 = H(gf) \beta$.  Pulling this equation back to the top row, we see that $(\deg g \cdot \alpha')^2 = H(gf) \beta'$.  Substituting $\alpha'^2 = H(f) \beta'$, we deduce that $H(gf) = (\deg g)^2 \cdot H(f)$.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm familiar with an other point of view of what you called cofiber sequence, could you briefly explain what you're doing?

Comment: Here, I'm using "cofiber sequence" in the sense of Puppe sequences; each arrow exhibits the cofiber of the previous arrow.

Comment: I assume cofiber map is a synonime for cofibration correct if wrong. I still don't understand how you built the diagram if with Puppe sequence you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppe_sequence).

Comment: Are you making the construction of Hopf Invariant for $g \circ f$ and $g$?

Comment: Could please expand? It's the step I'm not getting how to "pull this equation back" if I understood how you're trying to prove it.

Comment: 1) Starting with $S^{2n-1} \xrightarrow{f} S^n$, we get a Puppe sequence $S^{2n-1} \to S^n \to C_f \to S^{2n} \to S^{n+1} \to \cdots$.  I am looking at the terms surrounding $C_f$.  2) Yes, I am comparing the definition of the Hopf invariant for $gf$ and $g$.  3) $\alpha'^2 = H(g) \beta'$ is an equation that holds in the cohomology ring of $C_g$.   We examine the result after applying the map induced in cohomology by $C_{gf} \to C_g$.  The effects on the elements $\alpha', \beta'$ can be identified in terms of the maps between the corresponding spheres that make up $C_{gf}$ (resp. $C_g$).

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. Just last doubt: there is a natural topological map between $C_{gf} \longmapsto C_g$ or you taking the map in cohomology as the composition of the other three to make the diagram commute?

Comment: There is a commutative square with rows $gf$ and $g$ and columns $f$ and $\mathrm{id}$.  The cofiber of each row gives the desired map $C_{gf} \to C_g$.