# Continuos map between mapping cones $C_{f \circ g} \longmapsto C_f$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, homology-cohomology, spheres

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219999/exercise-1-p-428-hatcher-property-of-hopf-invariant) about Hopf Invariant I was able to prove that if $g: \mathbb{S}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^n$ is a map of degree $m$, then the Hopf invariant $H(g \circ f) = m^2H(f)$ using the fact that there is a natural map from $\psi : C_f \longmapsto C_{g\circ f}$ defined by $\begin{cases}(x,t) \to (x,t) \\ y \to g(y) \end{cases}$ which commutes with the squares (that are explicit in the linked question).

Now I have to prove that if $g: \mathbb{S}^{2n-1} \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^{2n-1}$ then $H(f \circ g)=mH(f)$. In order to do that I'd like to costruct an explicit map from $C_{f \circ g}\longmapsto C_f$ such the diagrams commute to induce the diagram in cohomology, but I didn't find one.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup, as I understand it, is that you're given $X \xrightarrow{g} Y \xrightarrow{f} Z$. Then define $C_{f \circ g} \to C_f$ by $z \mapsto z$ and $(x,t) \mapsto (g(x), t)$. In terms of diagrams, in case it's helpful:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f \circ g}>> Z @>>> C_{f \circ g} \\
@VV{g}V @| @VVV \\
Y @>{f}>> Z @>>> C_f
\end{CD}
$$
The left square clearly commutes, and so there should be an induced map on the cofibers.